# Restore system after accidentally purging python2

Tags: networking, 18.04, apt, python, python-2.7

My brother have purged python2 in his Ubuntu Desktop 18.04. That's what happened, Graphical Display Manager is failing. After logging in `tty`, I have tried to `update`, `--fix-missing` and `apt install python` but nothing worked.

It also may happen that the system's networking is not working as there is change in the network configuration recently (maybe that's why updating system did not worked). Pinging to 8.8.8.8 working though. I have setup the new static IP in the `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Now, How the system can be restored?

Comment: First: When you purge python2 you remove many other desktop packages so your system needs serious repair. Second:apt uses hostnames for update so if you have a DNS issue it will not work. Can you `ping ubuntu.com`? Third: note that 18.04 networking does not use `/etc/network/interfaces` See documentation for `netplan`. You have a bit of work ahead of you but it can be done. Try re-installing your desktop once you get your network working.

Comment: Many thanks @StephenBoston. After a thunderstorm, I am able to restore the system. So far it seems that the system running well. I have to reconfigure the network setup and then have to install both python-all and ubuntu-desktop package.

Comment: But I am not sure if it is the correct way to restore a 'python purged' system.